# Why there are two different tags thirdparty and third-party?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I think we should merge these two tags on stackoverflow. [third-party](/questions/tagged/third-party) and  [thirdparty](/questions/tagged/thirdparty)

Comment: **Tip:** You can use the `[tag:third-party]` syntax so you don't have to compose the links yourself.

Comment: @TomWijsman thats a useful tip.. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Completed.

Posting an answer to get this off the unanswered list.  Upvote if you agree (this answer is CW).